# float values error after numpy vstack

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem while using numpy vstack for float values with exponent e-5.
Both item_array and date_array are numpy.ndarray.
When I use **data = np.vstack((date_array,item_array))**, the element **3.04871703e-05** become to **3.0487170344**. Other elements are good. Does anyone can help me to fix this issue? Thanks

In [2]: item_array
Out[2]: 
array([  0.00000000e+00,  -1.81992510e-03,  -9.44964473e-03,
        -3.12464669e-03,  -5.42864845e-03,  -1.67769866e-03,
         **3.04871703e-05**,  -7.81295968e-03,  -1.12972557e-02,
        -1.69797339e-02,  -1.22161657e-02,  -1.93931514e-02,
        -1.11389637e-02,  -7.59505250e-03,   5.65141213e-03,
         4.81559901e-03,  -1.37724956e-02,  -1.51201763e-02,
        -2.55894748e-02,  -2.48333169e-02,  -2.56770574e-02,
        -3.21192961e-02,  -2.71028609e-02,  -2.84357450e-02])

In [3]: date_array
Out[3]: 
array(['"2016-05-03"', '"2016-05-04"', '"2016-05-05"', '"2016-05-06"',
       '"2016-05-07"', '"2016-05-08"', '"2016-05-09"', '"2016-05-10"',
       '"2016-05-11"', '"2016-05-12"', '"2016-05-13"', '"2016-05-14"',
       '"2016-05-15"', '"2016-05-16"', '"2016-05-17"', '"2016-05-18"',
       '"2016-05-19"', '"2016-05-20"', '"2016-05-21"', '"2016-05-22"',
       '"2016-05-23"', '"2016-05-24"', '"2016-05-25"', '"2016-05-26"'], 
      dtype='|S12')

In [4]: data = np.vstack((date_arry,item_array))

In [5]: data
Out[5]: 
array([['"2016-05-03"', '"2016-05-04"', '"2016-05-05"', '"2016-05-06"',
        '"2016-05-07"', '"2016-05-08"', '"2016-05-09"', '"2016-05-10"',
        '"2016-05-11"', '"2016-05-12"', '"2016-05-13"', '"2016-05-14"',
        '"2016-05-15"', '"2016-05-16"', '"2016-05-17"', '"2016-05-18"',
        '"2016-05-19"', '"2016-05-20"', '"2016-05-21"', '"2016-05-22"',
        '"2016-05-23"', '"2016-05-24"', '"2016-05-25"', '"2016-05-26"'],
       ['0.0', '-0.001819925', '-0.009449644', '-0.003124646',
        '-0.005428648', '-0.001677698', **'3.0487170344'**, '-0.007812959',
        '-0.011297255', '-0.016979733', '-0.012216165', '-0.019393151',
        '-0.011138963', '-0.007595052', '0.0056514121', '0.0048155990',
        '-0.013772495', '-0.015120176', '-0.025589474', '-0.024833316',
        '-0.025677057', '-0.032119296', '-0.027102860', '-0.028435744']], 
      dtype='|S12')

Comment: Isn't this just a display issue though, the real underlying values are still as expected?

Comment: Checkout https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html may be usefull.

Comment: In your case the dtype is S12, so the last entries might be just cut away? When it is S32, I still can see the e-5. I cannot reproduce your way, when I do exactly the same, I end up with an numpy array with dtype = '|S32'

Comment: Why are you stacking a float array with a string one?

Comment: What `numpy` version are you using?  In my tests the date array is `S12`, the result `S32`, which has space for `'3.04871703e-05'`.  Why do the dates have the extra layer of quoting?

Comment: I change the type of item_array from float to string '|S32', then it works. Thanks very much. In [2]: type(item_array[0]) Out[2]: numpy.float64 In [3]: item_array = item_array.astype('|S32') In [4]: type(item_array[0]) Out[4]: numpy.string_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote your script like that :

```
import numpy as np

item_array = np.array([0.00000000e+00, -1.81992510e-03, -9.44964473e-03,
                       -3.12464669e-03, -5.42864845e-03, -1.67769866e-03,
                       3.04871703e-05, -7.81295968e-03, -1.12972557e-02,
                       -1.69797339e-02, -1.22161657e-02, -1.93931514e-02,
                       -1.11389637e-02, -7.59505250e-03, 5.65141213e-03,
                       4.81559901e-03, -1.37724956e-02, -1.51201763e-02,
                       -2.55894748e-02, -2.48333169e-02, -2.56770574e-02,
                       -3.21192961e-02, -2.71028609e-02, -2.84357450e-02])

date_array = np.array(['"2016-05-03"', '"2016-05-04"', '"2016-05-05"', '"2016-05-06"',
                       '"2016-05-07"', '"2016-05-08"', '"2016-05-09"', '"2016-05-10"',
                       '"2016-05-11"', '"2016-05-12"', '"2016-05-13"', '"2016-05-14"',
                       '"2016-05-15"', '"2016-05-16"', '"2016-05-17"', '"2016-05-18"',
                       '"2016-05-19"', '"2016-05-20"', '"2016-05-21"', '"2016-05-22"',
                       '"2016-05-23"', '"2016-05-24"', '"2016-05-25"', '"2016-05-26"'])

data = np.vstack((date_array,item_array))

print data
```

And I get a good result :

```
[['"2016-05-03"' '"2016-05-04"' '"2016-05-05"' '"2016-05-06"'
  '"2016-05-07"' '"2016-05-08"' '"2016-05-09"' '"2016-05-10"'
  '"2016-05-11"' '"2016-05-12"' '"2016-05-13"' '"2016-05-14"'
  '"2016-05-15"' '"2016-05-16"' '"2016-05-17"' '"2016-05-18"'
  '"2016-05-19"' '"2016-05-20"' '"2016-05-21"' '"2016-05-22"'
  '"2016-05-23"' '"2016-05-24"' '"2016-05-25"' '"2016-05-26"']
 ['0.0' '-0.0018199251' '-0.00944964473' '-0.00312464669' '-0.00542864845'
  '-0.00167769866' '3.04871703e-05' '-0.00781295968' '-0.0112972557'
  '-0.0169797339' '-0.0122161657' '-0.0193931514' '-0.0111389637'
  '-0.0075950525' '0.00565141213' '0.00481559901' '-0.0137724956'
  '-0.0151201763' '-0.0255894748' '-0.0248333169' '-0.0256770574'
  '-0.0321192961' '-0.0271028609' '-0.028435745']]
```

If you don't write `dtype`, it should work well ;)

Comment: I don't see anything different in yours. What is the `dtype` of your `date_array`?  Of the stack?  The OP was showing the `repr` his array, which includes the `dtype` (and commas).  There's some other issue.

Comment: I change the type of item_array from float to string '|S32', then it works. Thanks very much.
 
In [2]: type(item_array[0])
Out[2]: numpy.float64

In [3]: item_array = item_array.astype('|S32')

In [4]: type(item_array[0])
Out[4]: numpy.string_